# Identification of a plant brasileira

Tags: identification

I live in Brazil (Rio de Janeiro) and this plant often appears in the garden even without being planted. Can someone tell me what kind it is?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is Jatropha podagrica - it has lots of common names. In India and some other countries, it's called the buddha belly plant because of the swelling in the stem near the base that gets larger as the plant ages; in other countries, it's known as gout plant or gout stick. It usually loses its leaves over winter, depending on climate, and may be killed altogether in colder countries, more information here https://toptropicals.com/html/toptropicals/plant_wk/jatropha_podagrica.htm